# Can we do multiple edit views in infopath?

Tags: 2013, infopath, view, edit

So I made some `Display views` in InfoPath and they have buttons on them to simulate tabs like navigation.

Each "tab" switch views. These views are not read only and we can enable edit item so each view becomes editable.

But how can I achieve this without having to go to the ribbon for editing?

I mean, I would like to add a button to my view that switch to edit mode like a button that switches views. Is it possible?